# Service fabric change application count without having to redeploy the whole package

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is is possible to decrease the instance count of an application hosted in Service fabric without having to redeploy the whole package.

When I deployed it the application instance count is set to -1. now I would like to reduce it to 3

Comment: Are you talking about Stateless Service instance count?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the powershell script I'm using. It will translate xml to powershell parameter and run `Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade` with it:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $ApplicationName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $ApplicationTypeVersion,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $ApplicationParameterFile
)
function Read-ApplicationParameters
{
    Param (
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [String]
        $ApplicationParameterFile
    )
    $applicationParameterXml = [Xml] (Get-Content $ApplicationParameterFile)
    $applicationParameter = @{}
    $applicationParameterXml.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | Foreach {$applicationParameter[$_.Name] = $_.Value}
    return $applicationParameter
}
$appParams = Read-ApplicationParameters $ApplicationParameterFile
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName $ApplicationName -ApplicationTypeVersion $ApplicationTypeVersion -ApplicationParameter $appParams -UnmonitoredAuto
```

1. Take latest application parameters xml file
2. Modify values you want to update (leave the other one untouched)
3. Connect to the cluster
4. Run `Get-ServiceFabricApplication`
5. Run the script above and take ApplicationName, ApplicationTypeVersion values from execution of point 4. ApplicationParameterFile is path to the newly modified xml file.
6. Monitor upgrade by using `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/MyApp`
7. Once it is done, verify parameters by running `Get-ServiceFabricApplication` again.